# Disable or Enable Auto-Healing on AWS using API or CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-opsworks

As an important attributes of Amazon, I'm curious about the topic which we can disable or enable auto-healing on AWS using API or CLI or we can't.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CLI for OpsWorks: [update-layer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/update-layer.html)

```
aws opsworks --layer-id <value> [--enable-auto-healing | --no-enable-auto-healing]
```

**Updates a specified layer.**

Required Permissions : To use this action, an IAM user must have a Manage permissions level for the stack, or an attached policy that explicitly grants permissions. For more information on user permissions, see Managing User Permissions .

```
--enable-auto-healing | --no-enable-auto-healing (boolean)
```

> Whether to disable auto healing for the layer.